# Intermittent problems EF6 on Azure connecting to remote MySQL DB

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, azure, entity-framework-6

I have a site on the Azure free subscription, which is C# on EF6 connecting to a MySQL database on a remote host. The application will run fine for some time, but then for an authenticated user, it will error out on an ObjectDataSource select event with the following:

```
Inner exception information (level 1):
    Exception type: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException
    Exception message: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Inner exception information (level 2):
    Exception type: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
    Exception message: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Request information:
    Request URL: https://xxx.azurewebsites.net:443/default.aspx
    Request path: /default.aspx
    User host address: 111.111.111.111
    User: xxx
    Is authenticated: True
    Authentication Type: ApplicationCookie
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxx

Thread information:
    Thread ID: 24
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxx
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Other times, for an unauthenticated user, it just won't load in the first place, with:

```
    Inner exception information (level 1):
    Exception type: System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
    Exception message: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See the inner exception for details of the failure.

Inner exception information (level 2):
    Exception type: System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
    Exception message: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.

Request information:
    Request URL: https://xxx.azurewebsites.net:443/
    Request path: /
    User host address: 111.111.111.111
    User: 
    Is authenticated: False
    Authentication Type: 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxx

Thread information:
    Thread ID: 64
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxx
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
```

or

```
Thread information:
    Thread ID: 27
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxx
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<EnsureConnectionAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<FirstOrDefaultAsync>d__25`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1.<FindAsync>d__d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Find[TUser,TKey](UserManager`2 manager, UserLoginInfo login)
   at TDT.Account.RegisterExternalLogin.Page_Load()
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.<LoadRecursiveAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Util.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaitable.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
```

My connections strings are like this: the 1st one is used for the ApplicationDbContext for Identity stuff, and the 2nd one is used by the EF Model:

```
<add name="IdentityConnection" connectionString="server=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx;user id=xxx;database=xxx;password=Password;persistsecurityinfo=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> 
<add name="context" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyM‌​odel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=111.111.11.11;user id=xxx;database=MyDB;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Since it is on the free Azure, and you can have 10 sites for free, I have uploaded an identical version of the site to another Azure subdomain, so when the first site errors, I check the second site, and that site connects to the DB perfectly well and the application loads normally. Anyone any ideas what is going on? Is it a restriction on the free Azure subscription for multiple users or a limited number of users/connections at one time? I read that there was a limit of 4 connections to a ClearDB MySQL, but this MySQL is completely separate and shouldn't have those restrictions. Although the 2nd site does load when the 1st errors, the 2nd site also produces errors if used at length.
thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the remote host doesn't block connection from Azure?

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't the 2nd site also have problems? Also, it can be working for some time just fine, and just stop working without warning.

Comment: IP for Azure services can vary. It doesn't seem like some restrictions issue since error clearly indicates that there is a problem with MySQL host. Can you show you connection string?

Comment: Can you check whether `ProviderIncompatibleException` contain another `InnerException`? It can be simple authentication issue.

Comment: I updated the question with more information re. the exceptions, but I think the `ProviderIncompatibleException` is always unauthenticated

Comment: Are you using MySQL connector? Could you tell me its version?

Comment: yes, it's version 6.9.5

Comment: any ideas on this? It's still happening and have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with one of my Java services that connected to an external MySQL server. I finally resolved the issue with help from a Azure technician.

If the issue is related to mine - it is caused by a SNAT table used for routing on Azure, [here is a post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2015/07/14/azure-snat.aspx) that describes the issue in detail.

I ended up sending keep-alive packets for all our TCP/IP socket connections. The other solution is to assign a PIP address, but I'm not sure if you can do that with an Azure Website.

I observed that the time needed to reconnect to our MySQL varied a lot, so the conclusion was that while your remote server thought that the connection was still open it wouldn't allow traffic from the same IP (the VIP of your website in Azure lingo) on the TCP level.

You may try setting a keepalive time to something below 4 minutes (our app is set to 60 seconds) for your DB connection:

```
server=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx;user id=xxx;database=xxx;password=Password;persistsecurityinfo=True;Keepalive=60;
```

I have almost no experience in C#, so check if the KeepAlive option is valid for your connector. It seems that it is according to [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/) site.